# Inertia of yo-yo goes to infinity, what is tension and acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

For this part, imagine that the string is wound around the center axle of a yo-yo; the axle radius is Raxle, but the yo-yo casing has a radius Rcasing≫Raxle and moment of inertia I≫mr2axle. In the limit the moment of inertia of the yo-yo I→∞ and the mass m of the yo-yo remains finite, what magnitudes would you expect for the tension T in the vertical section of string and the downward acceleration a of the center of mass?
Choose the option that best describes the limiting values of T and a under the conditions given.
Choose the option that best describes the limiting values of  and  under the conditions given.

A   T=0 and a=0

B   T=∞ and a=0

C   T=mg and a=0

D   T=∞ and a=g

E   T=0 and a=∞

F   T=∞ and a=∞

It's neither D, B, nor E
I'm very confused. If Inertia goes to infinity, then kinetic energy must go to infinity right? But if kinetic energy goes to infinity, tension goes to infinity thus the yo-yo flies upwards, right? And if tension is 0, a has to be infinite?

Comment: For a moment I was confused, too. I think what is meant is that one should analyze the case of the moment of inertia becoming arbitrarily large while the angular momentum stays limited because the mass stays finite (i.e. the mass would be located on a thing ring of ever larger radius, which makes the potential and the kinetic energy finite), which means that the angular velocity would go towards zero, i.e. it's a very, very slow yo-yo. Am I getting this wrong?

Comment: I think you're right, but in a previous part of the question which asked when I --> 0 the explanation is:  "The string provides the torque that transfers gravitational potential energy into rotational kinetic energy. In the limit I→0 the kinetic energy of rotation Krot→0 as well, so in this case the string has no work to do."

Comment: So that should mean when I --> infinity Krot --> infinity

Answer (score -1):

It is C. As I→∞ the yo-yo becomes increasingly unresponsive (has a smaller angular acceleration) to any applied torque; it will seem like it cannot begin rotating. If it can't rotate, the string can't unwind, so the center of mass can't fall, and the net force on the yo-yo must be zero.